# kali linux not taking keyboard input at login page when running on vmware

Tags: linux, keyboard, vmware, kali-linux, login-screen

I have recently installed VMWare to use Kali Linux on it but upon reaching the login page I wasn't able to type my username/password, it wasn't taking any keyboard input (even with a virtual keyboard)
I tried enabling virtual printers but that didn't help

Comment: Restart and Ctrl-Alt-F1 on restart to get into terminal mode.  Run:  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
. Restart and see if you can get into Kali. I am using Kali 2022.1 on VMware and it works fine. Make sure you downloaded the bare metal ISO from which to make a VM for Kali.

Comment: Ensure to install VMware Tools in the VM.

Comment: VMware Workstation?  VMware Player?  VMware Fusion?  Does this happen with just a Kali guest or with all guests?  If you're using Workstation, then go to VM > Settings > Options > General and try turning off "Enhanced keyboard" if it's enabled.

Comment: @john thank this worked for me. harrymc I was not prompted to install VMWare tools as normally happens when I create a VM and use an .ISO image. This time I used a vmware image and was not prompted to install VMWare tools

Comment: @jamesdlin Workstation, only with kali, the enhanced keyboard option was off

Answer (score 4):

Pragya,

I experienced the same issue. Are you able to send keyboard commands to the VM during boot? If so--try the following:

1. Reboot the VM
2. Select Advanced Boot Options
3. Boot the VM in recovery mode

In recovery mode, I was able to login with the default credentials and run the commands John recommended. I then rebooted the system and was able to login normally.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue as well. The options mentioned before did not work for me (recovery mode, apt clean stuff, enhanced keyboard off), but this worked:

1. Boot in recovery mode
2. `sudo apt reinstall open-vm-tools`